Hola tengo un error con Docker y laravel 11
El error es este Interface "Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection" not found
Este error se genera al tratar de utilizar la librería laravel exel en Docker. Cuando corro la aplicación fuera del contenedor funciona todo bien, entonces parece que el problema está dentro de mí contenedor.
adjunto archivo compose y dockerfile para ver si ven algo que esta mal configurado.
Si necesitan mas detalle de la publicación lo puedo proporcionar.
gracias!!!
Dokerfile:
FROM php:8.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    libcurl4 \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \ 
    unzip \
    libxml2-dev 

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY ./docker/apache/apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/public

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip curl \
    xml 
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg 

USER root

# RUN cp .env.example .env


WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer install

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    && chmod 775 -R /var/www 
    

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/storage

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/storage /var/www/bootstrap/cache

USER www-data

# Expose port 80 for Apache.
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache web server.
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Verifica la Instalación de la libreria y fijate que maatwebsite/excel este instalada en tu contenedor.


docker exec -it <tu_contenedor> bash
composer show maatwebsite/excel



El autoloading de composer tiene que estar funcionando, ejecuta esto:


composer dump-autoload



la versión de maatwebsite/excel que estás utilizando tiene que ser compatible con PHP 8.2. Revisa la documentación de la librería para confirmarlo.
Intenta ejecutar los comandos dentro del contenedor para ver si podes reproducir el error:


docker exec -it <tu_contenedor> bash
php artisan migrate



Te dejo un ejemplo de como se debería ver tu docker-composer.yml:


version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - APP_DEBUG=true
      - APP_KEY=base64:...
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: your_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db_data:



Saludos.
